# which delegate method will be invoked when click the tab of safari?

Tags: cocoa, delegates, safari, webkit

As we know , When we load frame from webpage of safari, we will invoke the delegate methods of webkit informal protocol(WebFrameLoadDelegate):

webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:

webView:didChangeLocationWithinPageForFrame:

and When we click or change the tabs of safari,which delegate methods will be invoked? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"We" don't know since this is entirely up to Safari what it fancies doing. At a guess, Safari encloses a WebView for each tab in a tabless NSTabView and switches between them. But again, that's just what it chooses to do at the moment, and might change its mind at any time.

As ever to your incessant questions, Safari has no plug-in API. WebKit does, but anything outside of that defined API is unknown, dangerous, and just asking for trouble. Please don't try it.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's very likely that each tab in safari is using it's own webkit control, as they don't reload when you switch between them.

So I'd have to venture a guess and say neither unless you're actually loading a page.

Comment: ok, and when click the tab , no one method will be invoked? I want to get the swf url in webpage , so when switch between them , I will show the url , so I must to know the delegate method, think you very much!